# PHP-CGI Called from NodeJS Always Returns 404

Tags: php, node.js

If I run a command such as `$ php-cgi /home/user/test.php` in my terminal, it will return the result of that PHP script, if the PHP script exists at the path provided and the permissions are all fine. But, for some reason, if I call `php-cgi` from NodeJS using the following:

```
child_process.exec("php-cgi /home/user/test.php",{
    env: {
        REQUEST_METHOD: method,
        CONTENT_LENGTH: body.length,
        QUERY_STRING: query,
        REDIRECT_STATUS: true
    }
}, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        if (displayErrors && stdout) {
            callback(stdout);
        } else {
            callback(error);
        }
    } else if (stdout) {
        console.log(stdout);
        callback(null, stdout);
    } else if (stderr) {
        callback(stderr);
    } else {
        callback(null, null);
    }
});
```

The result returned is always:

```
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24
Content-type: text/html

No input file specified.
```

I've confirmed that the command is being executed under the same user as my test in terminal, and I've tried changing the working directory as well, to no success.

The error returned *does* seem to be the same as would be for an actual 404; however, in this case, the file exists and I've confirmed that `php-cgi` works with it.

So, my question is: What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could replicate it on my Mac and found a way that seems to solve the issue.

As of why this happens, this [source](http://nginxlibrary.com/resolving-no-input-file-specified-error/) has a good explanation:

> If you are using nginx with php-cgi and have followed the standard
>   procedure to set it up, you might often get the “No input file
>   specified” error. This error basically occurs when the php-cgi daemon
>   cannot find a .php file to execute using the SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter
>   that was supplied to it. I’ll discuss about the common causes of the
>   error and it’s solutions.

Of course, you are not using nginx, but I think it applies here as well.

So following the advice from the article to adjust the code to make use of `SCRIPT_FILENAME` worked for me:

```php
child_process.exec("php-cgi",{
    env: {
        REQUEST_METHOD: method,
        CONTENT_LENGTH: body.length,
        QUERY_STRING: query,
        REDIRECT_STATUS: true,
        SCRIPT_FILENAME: '/home/user/test.php'
    }
}, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        if (displayErrors && stdout) {
            callback(stdout);
        } else {
            callback(error);
        }
    } else if (stdout) {
        console.log(stdout);
        callback(null, stdout);
    } else if (stderr) {
        callback(stderr);
    } else {
        callback(null, null);
    }
});
```